# Volume of polyhedron similar to prism but with different bases

Tags: geometry, volume, polyhedra

Imagine a polyhedron similar to a prism, with parallel but **different** bases. Let the bases have the same number of sides, so that every vertex on a base is connected to exactly one vertex on the other base (side faces are all quadrilaterals). See example figure:

[polyhedron similar to prism](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqpUe.png)

1. <del>Does it have a name? I found the term "prismatoid" but it seems like a more general family.</del>  See edit below.
2. Is it possible to compute its volume without integrating? By analogy with trapezoids in 2D, I'd be tempted to say $(A1 + A2) / 2 * h$, where $A1$ and $A2$ are the areas of the two bases.

**EDIT**

It's been rightly noticed that my picture is not a polyhedron because the left face is not planar. But I've found that what I describe should be a "prismoid", a subclass of prismatoids with both bases having the same number of vertices. But I cannot find extended information on such objects, so I think the second question still holds.

Comment: It's not a polyhedron, what's shown in the picture! The left "face" is warped!

Comment: Sorry for the bad image, I tried to edit it. The edges at the left are not crossing. Do you mean that the left face is not on a single plane? Is it mandatory in order to be a polyhedron?

Comment: All faces must be planar for it to be a polyhedron in the first place.

Comment: What for subsets of this "thing" having planar faces? Would it be impossible on a geometric basis?

Comment: If all side faces are planer, then they are either trapezoids or parallelograms. The solid is known as [prismoid](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Prismoid.html). Its volume is given by the formula ( same formula for the more general [prismatoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prismatoid)) $$V = \frac{h}{6}(A_0 + 4A_1 + A_2)$$ where $h$ is the height and $A_0, A_1, A_2$ are the areas for the top face, middle cross section and bottom face respectively.

Comment: I saw that formula for prismatoids, but I thought prismoids, being more "regular", i.e. not having triangular faces, could have a simpler formula, for example not requiring the cross section.

Comment: The areas, $A_0$ and $A_2$, are not enough. You can construct a pair of
prismoid w/ same $A_0, A_2$ and differnet volume. e.g consider the cuboid $[0,3] \times [0,1] \times [0,1]$ and the prismoid  with bottom face $[1,2] \times [0,3]$ at $z = 0$ and top face $[0,3] \times [1,2]$ at $z = 1$. Both of them has $A_0 = A_2 = 3$, However, volume of cuboid is $3$ while that of prismoid is $\frac{3 + 4\cdot 4 + 3}{6} = \frac{11}{3}$.